# Проигрывание видео

Tags: android

Приветствую!
Есть задачка, проигрывать в приложении различные видео.
Попробовал, все хорошо работает и в MediaPlayer, и в ExoPlayer2.

Но вот в чем проблема. И там и там принимаются на вход только прямые ссылки на файл. Если источники известны заранее, то еще как-то это можно обойти сформировав правильную ссылку заранее, для того же ютуба. Но что если они заранее неизвестны и это может быть любой источник со ссылкой на видео?

Есть ли какая-то возможность через плееры проиграть контент? Может я упустил какую-то важную особенность? Или есть какой-то выпрямитель ссылок всеядный?

Comment: типа чтобы воспроизводить видео онлайн с любого сайта?

Comment: Да, именно. Пока только через webview могу представить себе такое. Но хотелось бы через плеер.

Comment: [Это?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810306/2907755)

Comment: Оно будет работать только если скормить прямую ссылку на файл.